# Bug de redirecionamento em loop

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro

Procurei aqui no meta pela tag [chat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat) e entrei em um loop infinito de redirecionamento...

- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat

Bug:

[image: loop]

Comment: Confirmado no Chrome.

Comment: Confirmado no iOS Safari 7

Comment: Confirmado no Firefox 25.

Comment: Ninguém vai confirmar no IE? (hehe)

Comment: Vai acontecer em qualquer browser, o problema deve estar no servidor.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce as of 23/01/14, I'm assuming it's now fixed.